# Как определить в linux какие процессы находятся в swap?

Tags: linux, bash, swap

Нужен скрипт, выводящий список процессов, использующих swap. Должно быть отсортировано по объёму памяти процесса, находящемуся в swap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash

for proc_dir in /proc/*
do
    if [ -d "$proc_dir" ]
    then
        pid=$(basename "$proc_dir")
        if [[ $pid =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]
        then
            if grep -q "VmSwap" $proc_dir/status
            then
                swap_usage_nums=$(cat $proc_dir/status | grep VmSwap | awk '{ print $2 }')
                if (( swap_usage_nums > 0 ))
                then
                    swap_usage_unit=$(cat $proc_dir/status | grep VmSwap | awk '{ print $3 }')
                    cmdline=$(cat $proc_dir/cmdline | sed -e "s/\x00/ /g";)
                    echo "${swap_usage_nums}${swap_usage_unit} $cmdline"
                fi
            fi
        fi
    fi
done | sort -h -r
```

Пример работы:

```
4400kB /usr/bin/ruby -C/var/lib/pcsd -I/usr/share/pcsd -- /usr/share/pcsd/ssl.rb & > /dev/null &
3960kB /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d
2492kB /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
2492kB /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
2492kB /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
2492kB /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
2472kB /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
1884kB /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
1872kB /usr/share/journalbeat/bin/journalbeat -e -c /etc/journalbeat/journalbeat.yml -path.home /usr/share/journalbeat -path.config /etc/journalbeat -path.data /var/lib/journalbeat -path.logs /var/log/journalbeat
1300kB /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
1220kB /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
1132kB /usr/local/bin/node_exporter --collector.arp --collector.buddyinfo --collector.conntrack --collector.cpu --collector.cpufreq --collector.diskstats --collector.entropy --collector.filefd --collector.filesystem --collector.hwmon --collector.loadavg --collector.logind --collector.meminfo --collector.meminfo_numa --collector.mountstats --collector.netclass --collector.netdev --collector.netstat --collector.processes --collector.sockstat --collector.stat --collector.systemd --collector.textfile --collector.time --collector.uname --collector.vmstat --no-collector.bcache --no-collector.bonding --no-collector.drbd --no-collector.edac --no-collector.infiniband --no-collector.interrupts --no-collector.ipvs --no-collector.ksmd --no-collector.mdadm --no-collector.nfs --no-collector.nfsd --no-collector.ntp --no-collector.perf --no-collector.pressure --no-collector.qdisc --no-collector.runit --no-collector.supervisord --no-collector.tcpstat --no-collector.timex --no-collector.wifi --no-collector.xfs --no-collector.zfs --web.listen-address=[::]:9090 --collector.diskstats.ignored-devices=^(ram|loop|fd)\d+$ --collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points=^/(sys|proc|dev|run)($|/) --collector.textfile.directory=/var/lib/node_exporter/textfile_collector/
980kB /usr/sbin/keepalived
896kB /usr/sbin/keepalived
848kB /usr/sbin/keepalived
832kB /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6380
828kB /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6381
816kB /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
804kB /usr/bin/redis-sentinel *:26379 [sentinel]
660kB /usr/sbin/sshd -D
644kB /sbin/init
536kB ha_logd: write process
532kB ha_logd: read process
504kB /sbin/rpcbind -f -w
412kB /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 106:110
372kB /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
372kB /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
336kB ssh-agent -s
332kB ssh-agent -s
332kB ssh-agent -s
272kB /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
204kB /usr/sbin/cron -f
152kB /sbin/agetty --noclear tty1 linux
148kB /sbin/iscsid
140kB /usr/sbin/acpid
```

Возможные изменения будут [тут](https://gist.github.com/Sheridan/de1338f6b52adc10d5aea55c23fa3155)

Answer (score 3):

Ваш скрипт работает, но можно короче и без башизмов:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

for piddir in $(ls -d /proc/[0-9]*)
do
    c="$(test -e "${piddir}/cmdline" && cat "${piddir}/cmdline" | sed -e 's/\x00//g')"
    u="$(test -e "${piddir}/status" && awk '$1 == "VmSwap:" && $2 > 0 { print $2 $3; }' "${piddir}/status")"
    test "$u" != "" && echo "$u $c"
done | sort -h -r
```

Comment: Согласен. Я просто предпочитаю писать более привычный обычным программистам код. Для людей, незнакомых с башем конструкции вида `u="$(test -e "${piddir}/status" && awk '$1 == "VmSwap:" && $2 > 0 { print $2 $3; }' "${piddir}/status")"` малопонятны. Ну и имена переменных предпочитаю не однобуквенные.

Comment: Я считаю, что незнакомых с башом людей надо с ним знакомить :-)  Но это уже спорный момент.  Про переменные согласен.

Answer (score 3):

```bsh
grep -HP "VmSwap:[ \t]+[1-9]" /proc/[0-9]*/status |\
sed -r 's/(.*)status:VmSwap:[ \t]+([^\t ]+)[ \t]+([a-zA-Z]+)/printf "%-20s | %s\n" "size: \2\3"  "command: `cat \1cmdline`"/g' |\
/bin/bash |\
 sort -t':' -k '2,2' -nr
```

Теперь более подробно:

```
#Ищем все процессы у которых значение swap не начинается с 0, следовательно не пустое
grep -HP "VmSwap:[ \t]+[1-9]" /proc/[0-9]*/status
```

Далее

```
#Форматируем вывод, удаляя не нужные данные с помощью sed, группу замены рассмотрим отдельно
sed -r 's/(.*)status:VmSwap:[ \t]+([^\t ]+)[ \t]+([a-zA-Z]+)/.../g'

#Группа замены: "делаем форматированным вывод, что бы избежать явного цикла,
#просто подготавливаем команды для передачи интерпретатору, подставляя для каждого 
printf "%-20s | %s\n" "size: \2\3"  "command: `cat \1cmdline`"
```

Далее

```
#Передаем в интерпретатор подготовленные команды и получаем нужный результат
#отсортированный по максимальному значению используемой памяти в swap разделе.
/bin/bash |\
sort -t':' -k '2,2' -nr
```

---

Замеры по таймингу выполнения:
1-й предложенный вариант - real    0m4.828s
2-й предложенный вариант - real    0m1.268s
Мой вариант - real    0m0.122s